# FFMPEG - Verify frame order

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I have created a video of a large number of images using ffmpeg using the following command

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p /home/jake/Desktop/output.mp4
```

The command works and produces a video, however I need a way to verify that the images have been processed in the correct order as the files have quite obscure names. For example, the first 3 images in the sequence are:

1. `image_20150625T100000.000_550000328.png`
2. `image_20150625T100000.033_550330578.png`
3. `image_20150625T100000.067_550671379.png`

all the way up to

`image_20150625T100459.987_3546673942.png`

I have tried using the `-loglevel` switch on various different options in hope that one would output the file name of each frame processed, but none seem to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify that by fixing frame rate of input image in following command :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/3 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p /home/jake/Desktop/output.mp4
```

Note that 1/3 frame rate will have a duration of 3 seconds for each image. you can see yourself one by one, 3 seconds will be enough for verifying that images have pushed into ffmpeg in correct order.

Comment: I was more looking for a systematic way of doing it. Ideally by ffmpeg printing the name of each frame as it's processed. This is so I can write code to validate the output video. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: If you want to verify in that case, you can't verify it. because image2pipe demuxer uses "ff_img_read_packet()" function to merge all images but there is no verbose log that prints file path in that function. so if you really want to print all images which are passing demuxer, you must fix source code.